# Dual Boot with Win8.1

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

I just install Ubnutu 14.04 to my Windows 8.1 machine. Install looked until the reboot. The boot choice did not come up. System went strait to Windows. Help? Thank you, William

Answer (score 0):

Where you install your boot loader has to match what you set in your BIOS. Verify this and then we'll talk more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like maybe your Grub2 was not properly installed.  In a situation like this, the best thing to do is to simply re-install Grub2 from a Live environment.  Basically you'll have to put in the installation disc again, reboot the pc and make sure that it boots off the disc you just inserted, then having done that, you can go through the process of reinstalling grub2 to sda1 if that's the drive that Windows is booting from.  Don't worry, nothing will happen to your Windows installation.
You can get more detailed instructions [at the grub2 community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2) for how to do this.